# Can I set the mime type for a Blazor Server page?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

In traditional ASP.NET, I can do something like this:

```cs
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("{'some': 'json'}");
Response.End();
```

Can I do something similar in a Blazor Server page? I just want to go to a certain route and return a string instead of html.

Or am I better off looking into what options I have for creating a web API in ASP.NET Core 3?

Comment: "just want to go to a certain route": IMO, it's better to inject a navigation `NavigationManager` service and invoke `navManager.NavigateTo(url)` rather than change the Response. Becase most of the time Blazor communicates by SignalR(Websocket) after the connection has been established, in that stage, there's no HTTP Response at all.

Comment: I want to give a url to our GIS front end - something like `https://example.com/gis/layer1.geojson`. So I need the http response content type to be "text/plain"

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the url "https://example.com/gis/layer1.geojson" is not a Blazor page but a plain endpoint that returns "text/plain"?

Comment: Yes. I realise now that what I was asking was - what's simplest way to generate a `text/plain` document with an ASP.NET Core/Blazor Server app

Comment: If that's the case, you don't need the view file.  Try something like this: `HttpContext.Response.ContentType="text/plain"; return Json(new {Some= "json" });` (you might want to change it if you want to use the RazorPage)

Comment: So where are you suggesting I put the above code? In a `.cshtml` file?

Comment: it depends on the scenario, you can either put it within a Middleware, Controller, or Razor Pages.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found an [example](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DynamicallyGeneratingRobotstxtForASPNETCoreSitesBasedOnEnvironment.aspx) by Scott Hanselman. It shows you how to generate a dynamic `robots.txt` file with a `.cshtml` page.

Here's the above code re-written as a `.cshtml` file:

```cs
@page "/file.txt"

@{
    Layout = null;
    this.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "{'some': 'json'}" );
    await this.Response.Body.WriteAsync( bytes );
}
```

I'm assuming that you can't do this with a `.razor` page - since a component would be rendered by the `_Host.cshtml` file...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a common approach with FileExtensionContentTypeProvider in your Startup.cs

```
...
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
…
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
          ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings.Add(".dae", "text/xml");
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
  ...
        }
...
```

And, YES, you have to call yet another “empty” app.UseStaticFiles(); after your configurations because of the known bug https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9588